# Avoid hardcoding in If statement with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, plsql

I have a snippet of PL/SQL code that looks similar to this:

```
IF l_order = 'Cancelled At Order Stage' OR l_order = 'Stopped at Billing Stage' THEN
    Do something
END IF;

IF l_type = 'Internal' OR l_type = 'Contracted' THEN
    Do something else
END IF;
```

I'd like to avoid having the hard coded strings, so I considered a simple array. However, it seems like a lot of extra lines of code (creating a type, creating an array of the type, iterating through that array) just to do what I've got here.

What are the recommendations on what to do here? I know this is a very minimal issue and I'm probably micro optimising, but I'd look to know what good practice is.

Comment: You could parametrize the strings into local variables like `l_cancelled := 'Cancelled At Order Stage';` and keep them all at the top of your function/proc/package.

Comment: @mmmmmpie: That was my thought. Would you always recommend doing that to avoid hard coding, even if there's just a single variable? Secondly, would you always keep them at the top of the function/package, or would you put them just above the particular block they were needed, so they're never declared/created unless needed?

Comment: It depends on how parametrized you like your code. I've seen architects demand things like `char comma=',';` so YMMV entirely on that. Second, its dev/architect preference on where you define them. Does PL/SQL care where you populate them? No but readability might. If I have to go in behind you and work on your code I'd rather have those string declaration either a) stored in a table in the DB itself (like a flex field) or b) populated at the very beginning. Third, you shouldn't have variables declared and never used if you find yourself in that situation you are being too granular.

Comment: The benefit of replacing the hard-coded values with declared constants is partly to avoid repetition but largely to ease maintenance; if the value changes then you fix the constant, not all occurrences of the string. If you declare the constant too close to where the hard-coded value was anyway then you might still repeat it in different code and you're still having to find and replace things throughout the file - with only one ref. you might as well keep the hard-coded value. With all constants at the top of the stored unit, or in a dedicated package, you know exactly where to look for them.

Comment: Agreed, @AlexPoole. I'm looking for something ANSI has to say about it but can't find anything. Like what you do on 15 in blackjack... whatever you do just do it all the time.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Imagine I have a block of code that starts with two if statements which check for things. If those if statements are satisfied, the procedure is returned from. If not, we continue. The very next thing is a cursor with five or six items. Is it still okay practice to put that at the top of the procedure, even if you might never reach it?

Comment: Looks like a very poor design when fields like type or order are set by more or less free text

Comment: @Wernfried: I wouldn't disagree, but I'm stuck with it. A database rewrite is just out of the question

Comment: @AndrewMartin - if you're only declaring and using it that deep into your logic, in such a small scope, what's the point of the constant? You're still hard-coding the value, just very slightly earlier than you were anyway. Maybe I'm missing the point though.

Comment: @AlexPoole: I agree, it's still being hard coded. I'm converting this from a T/SQL environment to a PL/SQL environment. I'm trying to make any improvements I can, but we're largely stuck with the logic in the majority of cases. I know it's bad practice to hard code them (which is what is happening now), so I'm trying to change it. I could set up a package of functions, either of which is in charge of returning a particular constant value. I guess I'm just looking for best practice advice, insofar as is possible, with what I've got

Comment: I like the concept of flex field tables. It allows customers to store custom data without code changes. Example table employees (id, emp_id, full_name, job_id) jobs (job_id, job_code, description_id <<-this goes to flex) flex_tl (flex_id, product, segment1) Segment1 would house the "description" of the job. 1 place to change and it can be put in the front end to modify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$A := Hard-coding
$B := bad
$C := weigh
$D := advantage
$E := configurability
$F := cost
$G := reduced readability
```

$A is not always $B.  You have to $C the $D of $E against the $F of $G.

[People can only keep a small number of new variables in their head at once.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunking_%28psychology%29)  It's up to you to decide what in your system has meaning.  For example, if developers see the phrase "Cancelled At Order Stage" a dozen times a day, reading it requires no thought.  If you replace that phrase with C_CANCEL_STATUS your code becomes less readable.

---

Or maybe you just need a little PL/SQL syntactic sugar.  For example, using a pre-defined collection and the `member of` operator may help simplify things:

```
declare
    c_cancelled_statuses constant sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := 
        sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Cancelled At Order Stage', 'Stopped at Billing Stage');
begin
    if 'Cancelled At Order Stage' member of c_cancelled_statuses then
        dbms_output.put_line('Cancelled!');
    end if;
end;
/
```

---

All programmers understand that hard-coding can be bad (right?).  Hard-coding can hurt your code but probably won't kill it.

But I've seen several systems completely destroyed by [softcoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softcoding).  I know too many managers that think any line of code is "hard-coded", and that all logic should be stored in a configuration table.  Many horrible, proprietary programming languages have been built because of a a fear of hard-coding.  Don't feel too bad about occasionally hard-coding.

Comment: +1. I like this. I feel I'm being overly picky here. I think things are probably fine as they are. It's readable and immediately understandable and I think any changes I make will make it much less so.